# Declare All Function Parameters in R Without Calling the Function

Tags: r, function, debugging, parameters

I want to a function where I throw any given other function with multiple parameters that use both single and double quotes.

For example:

1. `just_params("some_function(param1="this",param2='that')")`

or

2. `just_params(some_function(param1="this",param2='that'))`

which results in the function not being called but two new string variables param1 and param2 being declared in the environment. Either options works but I think #1 would be easier.

Throwing this all in a string directly is tough because of a mix of double and single quotes. I am hoping to use this while debugging other people's code and am assuming that they are using double and single quotes willy-nilly.

Yes, I know I can just copy and delete the commas but sometimes I am debugging function calls with 20 parameters (also cringe, I know) but that just how it is and I don't want to go in and copy and paste and delete commas each time.

Comment: so basically `debugonce` without calling `some_function`? something like `list2env(as.list(str2lang("some_function(param1='this',param2='that')"))[-1L], .GlobalEnv)`?

Comment: Does `formals(the_function)` help?

Comment: I'd think that you'd want to create an environment e.g. some_function.debug.

Comment: I think since you are doing this for debugging you want to think a bit more generally, for example what are all of the parameters not just the named ones in the call. Also to check for namespacing.   I think some features of the `rlang` package could help here.    Also in R  double quotes would be for a string, back ticks would be for when there is an improper name.  So they are really different.

Comment: Just thinking outloud in my previous comment, because a general solution would require back tick support also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```r
just_params <- function(call) {
  # Get the expression that was in the call without evaluating it.
  
  call <- substitute(call)
  
  # Expand all arguments to their full names.  This needs the
  # called function to exist and be visible to our caller.
  
  call <- match.call(get(call[[1]], mode = "function", 
                         envir = parent.frame()), 
                     call)
  
  # Change the name of the function to "list" to return the arguments
  
  call[[1]] <- `list`
  
  # Evaluate it in the parent frame
  
  eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
}

some_function <- function(param1, param2, longname) {}

just_params(some_function(param1 = "this", param2 = 'that', long = 1 + 1))
#> $param1
#> [1] "this"
#> 
#> $param2
#> [1] "that"
#> 
#> $longname
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Notes:

- If the call abbreviated a name you'll see the full name (the example used `long` instead of `longname`)
- If the call used an expression, it will be evaluated (the example used `1 + 1` but returned `2`.
- The type of quotes is not retained.

Comment: This is really neat, but I think a limitation is that it is only setting the parameters that are explicitly set, but if I were debugging I might want to explicitly set others.

Comment: I think it's a bit of an xy problem.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do anything, just making a comment.

Comment: I think im missing something. I ran your code and now I have just_params and some_function in my global environment, but that's it. Sure, the parameters were returned by the final just_params call but they aren't declared in my global environment. I feel that your solution user2554330 is close, but again, only the functions are declared in my global, not the params.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the list that is returned.  If you want to assign to those variables in the global environment, just use something like `for (n in names(thelist)) assign(n, thelist[[n]], envir = globalenv())`.  You could put that line into the function, but I'd call that a bad design:  next week you might want to assign them somewhere else.

Comment: Adding that line worked exactly as expected, thank you so much!